# System resource exceeded when appending a query Access 2016

Tags: ms-access

I currently work as a data conversion specialist and we are trying to move from Access 97 to Access 2016. We have been successful so far, but now I am having an issue with a query that has over 500,000 entries in it. I am trying to append this query to a FoxPro Table and I have been getting this error "System resource exceeded". I am linking to an existing table through an ODBC driver and an Advantage Streamline SQL Data Source I created.I am aware that Access does have a 2GB limit. The query I am trying to append is not complex, but it is lengthy. The database and the table is on our server that we hold all of our data. Some Solutions that I have tried are:

1. Changing the OLE/DDE timeout amount to the max (999999999) seconds:
   At first this seemed to work as the query continued to run, but then I got another error stating that I was having a criteria mismatch so then
   2: I checked for null and wrapping my SELECT fields with a NZ() function for each field.

After this, I got the System resource exceeded error again.

The good thing is that the old version of Access (97) works well and gets the job done, but gets it done SLOWLY. It takes around 5-8 hours to run these large queries.

Is there another way to combat this error?

Here is a snippet of my SQL statement if it helps resolve this issue:

```
SELECT IIf(IsNull([GADATE]),Nz([GADATE]),DatePart("yyyy",[GADATE])) AS 
FISYRToUse
FROM AGLDET;
```

There are around 36 columns similar to this one that I am trying to append to this table with over 500,000 rows.

Again, thanks in advance. If there is any way to improve my question then please let me know

Comment: How about dumping your query result in a txt or csv file and importing the txt or csv file in FoxPro?

Comment: You say "append" multiple times, but the query you show is a SELECT statement.  Are you using this SELECT statement with an INSERT statement?  You also say that you have 36 similar columns, but it's not clear how you would append 36 columns individually.  Do you instead mean "update" rather than append?  Either way, I assume that what you shared is not the complete statement.  Sometimes a shortened snippet is useful, but if you are seeking help with a particular error, it does not help to truncate your statements.

Comment: The IIF statement is redundant since it is already checking for null, but in the true case (meaning you have already determined that [GADATE] is null), the call to NZ() function is not necessary.  Although this won't solve your problem, this is more efficient:  `SELECT IIf([GADATE] Is Null, Null, Year([GADATE])) AS FISYRToUse FROM AGLDET;`  But as it turns out, the Year() function already handles null, so you could just use `SELECT Year([GADATE]) AS FISYRToUse FROM AGLDET;`

Comment: You state that you are aware of the 2GB limit, but you offer no further analysis of your data in that regard.  Being aware of something doesn't mean that you can ignore it.  36 columns of **over** 500,000 records can easily exceed the 2GB maximum, especially if that includes multiple text columns. (Does necessary meta-data also play into that limit?)  Have you tried something as simple as adding a WHERE clause to purposefully limit the data set?  If that works, you could segment the complete source into smaller chunks.  That's a good technique to have in your set of data conversion "tricks".

Comment: I am appending it. I did not include the INSERT portion of my SQL statement because that is not where the problem is. I have though about a where clause appending smaller chunks, but I was trying to see if there was a solution to where I did not have to do that. If I do have to come to that solution of breaking it down, then I will.

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
SELECT Nz(Year([GADATE])) AS FISYRToUse
FROM AGLDET;
```

or:

```
SELECT IIf([GADATE] Is Null, "", Year([GADATE])) AS FISYRToUse
FROM AGLDET;
```

For test:

```
SELECT Year([GADATE]) AS FISYRToUse
FROM AGLDET
WHERE [GADATE] Is Null;

SELECT Year([GADATE]) AS FISYRToUse
FROM AGLDET
WHERE [GADATE] Is Not Null;
```

Comment: I had tried the first one, but that did not work, now I have tried the second one and I am still getting the System Resource Exceeded error

Comment: Then try the two test queries. If they won't run, something else is going on. And "did not work" is not very useful.

Answer (score 0):

I would send that data + query out to a temp external accDB. And then try exporting that to the FoxPro database.

This would eliminate the iff(), nz() expressions etc.

Also, you should be getting about 100,000 rows per second here. Why this is taking so long does not make sense??

While the data and tables are on a server, you are also running the export and programs on that server also, right? If you using a client work station attached to the server, then you  pulling data down the network pipe and back up - that will be slow.

100k rows per second should be about the "ball park" rate of data transfer you get here.

Access 97 is old, and thus would use less memory, less CPU and run faster then newer versions. For the last 20 years, every new version of software takes more disk space, more memory, more CPU and does run slower - so this information would not be new to you.

Also, if you can, try a MSI version of Access in place of a CTR version. The reason for this is that CTR versions of office/Access are app-v (virtualized applications), and they tend to not release memory and resources, and worse they use much more memory and resources.

Another idea would be to export the data as FoxPro/dbase format, but to a external file, and then use FoxPro or the other application to import + append.

So, there are several things going on here, and this VERY slow process suggests that some BIG details are being left out here. If you working or shuffeling the data over a network, then that would certainly explain the slow issue.

However, Access 97 as noted should and would be the fastest here by a considerable margin. Like every software system I used, the next version is slower, takes more memory, more CPU and more resources. So the next version of Word, or Excel or Access or "what ever" always runs slower and takes more resources.

So you not going to get a speed up here by using later versions. And of course after Access 97, then office supported uni-code (a really big hit in performance).

So using a newer version always going to be slower - can't think of any exception in the last 25 years.

I would thus export the data to a accDB file, and then your NEXT export will not have those conditions (edit: I mean expressions that tax the memory system). This may well fix the memory leak issue. However, as noted, if you can, using a non CTR version of Access. (and 2016 versions are hard to get/find).